# How to remove the hash "#" symbol from url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

The website that I'm editing right now, every link at switching pages has hash symbol. And the page doesn't refresh everytime I switch and sticks on the last position of the site.

Where can I find the code and remove the hash from the url.
Does removing it will make the pages refresh everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue is a Single Page Application framework. That means you don't have full page loads, instead page content is swapped out dynamically on the client.

Assuming you're using [vue router](https://router.vuejs.org), you can switch to `historyMode` which won't use `#` for urls and instead real urls.

From [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html):

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.
>
> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:
>
> ```js
> const router = new VueRouter({
>  mode: 'history',
>   routes: [...]
> })
> ```

This will get you "normal" urls as seen anywhere else on the web.

Comment: I'm still searching the web for an answer, luckily you gave me what I need. I spent almost half an hour just to get the hash symbol removed. 

Anyway, thank you so much! Stay safe.